# invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Working on a project that reads integers from a file and puts them into a 2D array. I tested it with a 1D array but when I tried it with a 2D array I kept getting this error "invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript" in my class called "Image" in this function:

```
void Image::read(int* arr)
{
//Nested loop that reads the file
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            inputFile >> arr[i][k]; //Here's where I get the error
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    Image test("colorado1.dat"); //File with the integers

    test.setWidth(500);
    test.setHeight(500);

    int array[test.getHeight()][test.getWidth()];

    test.read(array);
    //Loop to test if the function worked
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 500; k++)
        {
            cout << array[i][k] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly you don't understand about the error? `arr` is an `int *`, therefore `arr[i]` is an `int`, and `arr[i][k]` is an obvious error, just like `int x=4; int y=x[2];` would be too. What exactly don't you understand, here? You will also get another compilation error in your `main()`, which may point you towards a big, honking clue, as well. Furthermore, your `main()` declares a variable-length array, which is a non-standard compiler extension, and is not valid C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this function signature:

```
void Image::read(int* arr);
```

Here, you've said that the type of `arr` is `int*`, a pointer to an integer. As a result, when you write

```
arr[i][k]
```

C++ says "hold on a second... `arr` is an `int *`, so `arr[i]` is an `int`, and you can't apply the square bracket operator to a pair of `int` values."

To fix this, you'll need to change up the way that you handle parameters to this function. You could either pass in an `int**`, which would represent a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, or consider using something like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, which is safer and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks so much! Been staring at that too long thinking it was a way more complicated issue lol